# Using ruby aws-sdk V2 to indicate if static website is configured

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a large number of S3 Buckets configured for static web hosting and I'm trying to use the Ruby aws-sdk to iterate through the list in order to print out various attributes like the index document, error document, redirection rules, etc.

Unfortunately, some of the buckets are not configured for static hosting. I need to skip those buckets to avoid getting an error.

I can't figure out how to detect if a bucket is configured for static hosting so the following code throws an error. See below.

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
s3.buckets.take(3).each do |bucket|
  puts "Name = #{bucket.name}"
  puts "Index Document = #{bucket.website.index_document}"
end
```

The error that is returned, because I'm not catching it is...

```
The specified bucket does not have a website configuration (Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration)
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take a short cut and just catch the error.

```
require 'aws-sdk'

s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

my_buckets = s3.buckets.map

my_buckets.each do |bucket|
  begin
    puts bucket.name
    puts bucket.website.error_document

  # if a website is not configured it's going to throw an error when you try to access bucket.website.error_document\
  # rescue the error, even though this seems like there should be a more elegant way to handle this.
  rescue Aws::S3::Errors::NoSuchWebsiteConfiguration => e
    puts e.message
  # Buckets that are just there to provide a redirect for www versions of the domain will also throw an error
  rescue Aws::S3::Errors::PermanentRedirect => e
    puts e.message
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
  end
end
```

Comment: I would love to know a more elegant way to handle this.